# Call a API synchronously inside For Each loop in android Kotlin Coroutines with Flow getting Error

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Call a API  synchronously inside For-each loop in android Kotlin Coroutines using Flow.

Also i need to wait all the API calls need to complete without blocking the Main Thread.

```
fun getLatesData(): Flow<Model> = flow {
        emit(getFirstList())
    }.flatMapLatest { data ->
        flow {
            val responseList = mutableListOf<String>()

            data.items?.forEach { datalist ->

                val response = getCreatedDate(datalist.Id)


                response.collect{count->
                    responseList.add(count.check)
                }
                val countData = Model(
                    datalist = data,
                    responseListCount = responseList
                )
            }
            emit(countData)
            
        }
    }
  
     private fun getCreatedDate(Id: String?)= flow {
            try {
                val response =  repoApi.getCount(Id)
                emit(response)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)

 @Headers(
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    )
    @GET("getCount/{Id}")
    suspend fun getCount(@Path("Id")Id: String?): response
```

**ERROR**-`kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.AbortFlowException: Flow was aborted, no more elements needed`

For the first iteration Data is emitting properly, but second time onwards getting above mentioned error.

Run a API call without blocking the UI thread inside for loop with Flow. Thank in advance.

Comment: There's not enough info here to understand what you're doing. What type is `data.items`? What type does `getCreatedDate` return and is it a suspend function? How can you emit `countData` outside the scope it was created in? How are you calling `emit()` outside a FlowProducer lambda? Where is `responseList` declared, and can it be local to this function?

Comment: @Tenfour04  -Please check the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense for `getCreatedDate()` to return a flow. A Flow is for a stream of values, not a single value. It can just be a suspend function.

```
private fun getCreatedDate(id: String?) =
    try {
        repoApi.getCount(id)
    } catch (e: Exception) { 
        // Catching all exceptions is an antipattern. Be specific and rethrow unexpected ones.
        if (e !is IOException || e !is HttpException) throw e
        e.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
```

Your other code can be simplified. No reason to create a flow of a single item and then flat map it. Just create the single flow directly. And use `mapNotNull` to more simply create your response list.

```
fun getLatesData(): Flow<Model> = flow {
    val data = getFirstList()
    val responseList = data.items?.mapNotNull { getCreatedDate(it.id)?.check }.orEmpty()
    val countData = Model(
        datalist = data,
        responseListCount = responseList
    )
    emit(countData)
}
```

---

Edit: I just realized that we are ultimately ending up with a Flow of a single item here, which is the same nonsensical situation as I mentioned about `getCreatedDate()`. The whole thing should be a suspend function like this:

```
suspend fun getLatesData(): Model  {
    val data = getFirstList()
    val responseList = data.items?.mapNotNull { getCreatedDate(it.id)?.check }.orEmpty()
    return Model(
        datalist = data,
        responseListCount = responseList
    )
}
```

If the API can handle doing the requests in parallel, this may be faster:

```
suspend fun getLatesData(): Model  {
    val data = getFirstList()
    val responseList = coroutineScope {
                data.items?.mapNotNull { async { getCreatedDate(it.id)?.check } }.orEmpty()
        }.awaitAll()
    return Model(
        datalist = data,
        responseListCount = responseList
    )
}
```

Comment: In edit, I think the OP deliberately emitting `getFirstList()` first before emitting the processed data, assuming they have use case to handle and show some sort of UI with first list and update it after api calls,  marking it suspend will negate that use case!

Comment: @RajanKali It's a flow that emits a single item, but then the `flatMapLatest` flow operator is used on it. Nothing will ever see that first emitted item except the inside of the `flatMapLatest` lambda.

Answer (score 1):

No need to create an extra `flow` and collect it, you could convert `getCreatedDate` to suspend instead and easily use it inside `for-loop` of `flow` builder

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
fun getLatestData(): Flow<Model> = flow {
    emit(getFirstList())
}.flatMapLatest { data ->
    flow {
        val responseList = data.items?.mapNotNull { getCreatedDate(it.Id)?.check }.orEmpty()
        emit(Model(dataList = data, responseListCount = responseList))
    }
}

private suspend fun getCreatedDate(Id: String?): Response? =  
    try { repoApi.getCount(Id) } 
    catch (e: Exception) { 
        e.printStackTrace() 
        null
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When a flow is aborted, the Coroutines framework throws the AbortFlowException to indicate that the flow collection should be stopped. This exception is caught internally by the flow framework. Just add suspend function.

```
suspend fun getLatesData(): Flow<Model> = flow {
    emit(getFirstList())
}.flatMapLatest { data ->
    flow {
        val responseList = mutableListOf<String>()

        data.items?.forEach { datalist ->

            val response = getCreatedDate(datalist.Id)


            response.collect{count->
                responseList.add(count.check)
            }
            val countData = Model(
                datalist = data,
                responseListCount = responseList
            )
        }
        emit(countData)
        
    }
}

 private suspend fun getCreatedDate(Id: String?)= flow {
        try {
            val response =  repoApi.getCount(Id)
            emit(response)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)

 @Headers(
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    )
    @GET("getCount/{Id}")
    suspend fun getCount(@Path("Id")Id: String?): response
```